# How to properly convert a MATLAB code to Fortran 95 or above?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, fortran

I have written a Matlab code for CGR method which works fine. Here it is:

**MATLAB CODE**

```
% Generalized Conjugate Residual Algorithm
% Solves M*x=b (J*dx=-F)

function [x,converged]=gcr_Mfree(F,Cnew,Cold,Fold,alpha);

% define global variables
global h n M;


%Change above

b        =  -F               ;  
tol      =  5.E-3            ;
maxiter  =  length(b)        ;
x        =  zeros(maxiter,1) ;
r        =  b                ; % we need this when calculating r_new 
normr(1) =  norm(r)          ;

alpha2   =  1e-6             ;  % alpha2 is the epsilon in the report!

for iter=1:maxiter

%Get preliminary search direction
p(:,iter) = r ;

%% Approximate the Jacobian(M) residual product
%alpha2    =  1.E-6                        ;
Cnew(1:n)  =  Cnew(1:n)+alpha2*r           ;
% Cnew(1)   =  Cold(1)                      ;
F2         =  Funct2(Cnew,Cold,Fold,alpha) ;
Mr         =  1/alpha2*(F2-F)              ;     
Mp(:,iter) =  Mr                           ;

%% Orthogonalize search direction
for j=1:iter-1
p(:,iter)  = p(:,iter)  -Mp(:,j)'*Mp(:,iter)*p(:,j)  ;
Mp(:,iter) = Mp(:,iter) -Mp(:,j)'*Mp(:,iter)*Mp(:,j) ;
end
%norm(Mp(:,iter))

%Normalize search direction
p(:,iter)  = p(:,iter)/(norm(Mp(:,iter)))  ;
Mp(:,iter) = Mp(:,iter)/(norm(Mp(:,iter))) ;


%Update solution and residual

alpha2 = r'*(Mp(:,iter))/( (Mp(:,iter))'*(Mp(:,iter))) ;
%alpha2
x      = x+alpha2*p(:,iter)                            ;
r      = r-alpha2*(Mp(:,iter))                         ; 

%Check convergence
normr=norm(r);
%fprintf('norm(r) = %g iter = %g\n',normr,iter+1);
if(normr < tol)
%fprintf('GCR Converged, iter = %g\n',iter+1);
converged=1;
break;
end

end %for loop

if(normr > tol)
fprintf('SOLUTION DID NOT CONVERGE!!');
converged=0;
end
```

And here is my last version of Fortran code :

```
    SUBROUTINE gcr_Mfree(F2  ,Cnew,Cold,C_Fold,IGG,JGG,x    ,converged)

        !**** FUNCTIONS TO BE SOLVED ****
        ! Generalized Conjugate Residual Algorithm
        ! Solves M*x=b (J*dx=-F)


        ! Use somemodule
        ! Arguments declarations
        IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)

        INTEGER :: IGG,JGG
        real*8, dimension(:),   ALLOCATABLE :: x
        real*8, intent(out)                 :: converged  !<
        REAL*8, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: F2,F22,Cnew,Cold,C_Fold,p,Mp 

        ! Variable declarations
        real*8 :: tol  
        real*8, DIMENSION(:),   ALLOCATABLE :: r,b,Mr,F2V,F22V,CnewV,ColdV,C_FoldV,alpha2
        integer :: i,j,maxiter,normr,iter

        MASK = SIZE(F2)
        ALLOCATE(F2V(1:MASK))
        ALLOCATE(CnewV(1:MASK))
        ALLOCATE(ColdV(1:MASK))
        ALLOCATE(C_FoldV(1:MASK))
        !*********** RESHAPING MATRICES TO VECTORS.........
        F2V    = RESHAPE(F2  ,(/MASK/))
        CnewV  = RESHAPE(Cnew,(/MASK/))
        ColdV  = RESHAPE(Cold,(/MASK/))
        C_FoldV = RESHAPE(C_Fold,(/MASK/))

        b       = -F2V                 !(why minus?)
        tol     = 5.E-2
        alpha2  = 1e-6 ! alpha2 is the epsilon in the report!
        maxiter = size(b)

        DEALLOCATE(x)
        ALLOCATE(x(1:maxiter))
        x       = 0.0D0       !GUIdE: ""m2f: x = zeros(maxiter,1)""


        r       = b ! we need this when calculating r_new
        ! normr(1) = norm2(r)                             !!!! Norm


        DO iter=1,maxiter

            !Get preliminary search direction

            DO i=1,iter
                p(:,i) = r
            ENDDO

            ! Approximate the Jacobian(M) residual product
            CnewV = CnewV + alpha2*r
            Cnew = RESHAPE(CnewV,(/IGG,JGG/))

            F22 = CNF2(Cnew,Cold,Fold,DT)
            F22V= RESHAPE(F22V,(/MASK/))

            Mr = (1/alpha2)*(F22V-F2V)      !GUIDE: (The apporximated Jacobian matrix)

            DO i=1,iter
                Mp(:,i) = Mr
            ENDDO

            !! Orthogonalize search direction
            do j=1,iter-1
          !m2f: p(:,iter) = p(:,iter) -  Mp(:,j)'* Mp(:,iter) * p(:,j)
                p(:,iter) = p(:,iter) -  Mp(j,:) * Mp(:,iter) * p(:,j)

          !m2f: Mp(:,iter) = Mp(:,iter) - Mp(:,j)'* Mp(:,iter) * Mp(:,j)
                Mp( :, iter ) = Mp( :, iter ) - sum( Mp( :, j ) * Mp( :, iter ) ) * Mp( :, j )
            end do
            !norm(Mp(:,iter))

            !Normalize search direction
            ALLOCATE(p(1:IG,1:JG))
            ALLOCATE(Mp(1:IG,1:JG))

            p(:,iter)  =  p(:,iter) / (norm2(Mp(:,iter)))
            Mp(:,iter) = Mp(:,iter) / (norm2(Mp(:,iter)))


            !Update solution and residual


            !call gemv(Mp, r, y [,alpha][,beta] [,trans])
            IF(iter.EQ.1) THEN
            SUM1 = dot_product(Mp(:,iter),r)
            ELSE
            DO I=1,MASK
            SUM1 = SUM ( Mp(:,MASK) * r )
            ENDDO
            ENDIF

            IF ((iter.EQ.1) THEN)
            alpha2 = SUM1 / SUM(Mp(1:iter,:) * Mp(:,1:iter))

            x = x + alpha2 * p(:,iter)
            r = r - alpha2 * Mp(:,iter)      ! where is the *(Cnew - C)?


            !Check convergence
            normr=norm2(r)     
            norm
            !fprintf('norm(r) = !g iter = !gNewLine',normr,iter+1);
            if (normr < tol) then
                !fprintf('GCR Converged, iter = !gNewLine',iter+1);
                converged=1
                exit
            end if


            END DO !for loop

            if (normr > tol) then
            write(*,*) 'GCR SOLUTION DID NOT CONVERGE!'
            converged=0
            end if

            RETURN
            END subroutine gcr_Mfree
```

Here are the main problems of converting form MATLAB to FORTRAN :

1. I don't know how should I find the norm of vectors and matrices for converging conditions? There is an intrinsic statement (nomr2) at 2008 standard. 
   [norm2 statement in 2008 standard](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/NORM2.html)
2. I don't know how to appropriately update code to calculate p, mp, alpha2 ?

alpha2 equation :

```
 alpha2 = r'*Mp(:,iter)) / (Mp(iter,:) * Mp(:,iter))

 alpha2 definition in MATLAB when iter = 2
  alpha2 = (Nx1)'*(Nx2) / (Nx2)' * (Nx2)
               (1x2)    /     (2x2)
                      (1x2)
```

I found **gemv** function and this link which describes the vector to matrix array operations.

[gemv function](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/520750)

Comment: Please be more specific... A vector is a 1D array, the concept of rows and columns does not apply here! For a 2D array, you could have 1xN and Nx1 arrays, which will correspond to a row and column vector respectively. But then you could use `transpose()` again. `forall` is just a construct/statement for assigning values to an array.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt The RHS of my equation is scalar which is a zero rank array. The LHS consists of a complicated vector to vector multiplication which should give a scalar at the end. In MATLAB, simply, I can use **'** or **transpose**. But in Fortran it is a hell of problem...

Comment: Isn't that just the [`dot_product()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/DOT_005fPRODUCT.html)?

Comment: There is nothing as column or row vector in Fotrtan. Really nothing. There are just 1D arrays and arrays of higher dimensions. Specify what you mean. I am voting to close the question as it is very unclear. If you have any code you struggle with, you must show it.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt It seems it is not. Here is the equation that I have:  **alpha2 = dot_product(r,Mp(:,iter)) / (Mp(iter,:) * Mp(:,iter))** I want r to be transposed. the dimension of Mp and RHS of my equation is going to change at every iteration.

Comment: New information belongs to the question itself, not in the comments, use the **edit** link below the question. Which array in that question you call a vector?

Comment: You probably mean `alpha2 = dot_product(r,Mp(:,iter)) / dot_product(Mp(iter,:) , Mp(:,iter))`

Comment: Are you trying to solve a least square problem here? Fortran cannot do that by itself, you would need external libraries like BLAS/LAPACK for that task!

Comment: @AlexanderVogt this is a Conjugate Gradient Residual algorithm. I have written the code in MATLAB. I need to change it to FORTRAN,

Comment: `(Mp(iter,:) * Mp(:,iter))` is not defined for a non-square matrix...

Comment: Is the * in Matlab elementwise multiplication or a do product or what is it? I can't see any reason for doing any transpose in Fortran. Perhaps show also the mathematical formulation of that line.

Comment: I give up... There are so many conflicting pieces of code given here, so many errors - how could `(Mp(:,iter))'*(Mp(:,iter))` work beyond the first iteration in Matlab? Please get your question in order...

Comment: @AlexanderVogt it is working in MATLAB. be sure. I have demonstrated the size of matrices at each iteration. If you follow it, you will see that **alpha2** is going to be a 1st rank array which has **iter** number of elements at the end. sorry for bothering. I thought it is going to be simple than this.

Comment: Please define mathematically what the equation does, it is not clear to me at all.

Comment: I think @VahidAttari needs to understand what the line does in MATLAB before he tries to implement it in fortran...

Comment: Dear @Ross. Thank you for the comment. Definitely, we should know what is happening mathematically to be able to change a code to another language. I have posted the mathematical definition of that line at the end of the post and I don't know why you and **vladimir** are talking about the definition of that line. As it is demonstrated at the end of the post, at 1st iteration, I have a scalar value in MATLAB. At the 2nd iteration, I have a vector with 2 elements and this continues so far. But it is MATLAB and interpreted language and it is easy to handle these array operations.

Comment: The '/' operation in MATLAB is matrix division and '*' is matrix multiplication. As stated by others, fortran does not have any knowledge about rows or columns and any matrix operations require libraries or for you to build your own subroutine. If you wish to port the code to fortran you should look up how to call matrix operations from fortran.

Comment: I guess it will be useful to add matlab tag in the Question. Also, I am wondering if in Matlab, Mp( :, iter ) represents an Nx1 matrix rather than an N x iter matrix (the latter is Mp(:, 1:iter) ?). If so, `alpha2 = sum( r * Mp(:,iter) ) / sum( Mp( : , iter ) * Mp( :, iter ) )` seems simply be okay (where `*` in Fortran means element-wise multiplication rather than matrix multiplication).

Comment: Sorry, even if you bold my name, you really didn't get it. You did not explain the mathematics AT ALL. Your definition is not standard a mathematical way how to write equations in linear algebra. I had to guess what `/` and `*` mean and I only got to know it from the comments and answers by others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of "zeroth-order" version of converted code. Because I am not very familiar with Matlab syntax, the code may include some mistakes or may not reflect the original code precisely (I referred to [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/index.htm)), but I guess it will at least be useful as a starting point for more precise conversion...

```
subroutine gcr_Mfree( F, Cnew, Cold, Fold, alpha, x, converged )
    !! Generalized Conjugate Residual Algorithm
    !! Solves M*x=b (J*dx=-F)

    !! (M(:,:) does not seem to be used in the code...
    !! Funct2() may be multiplying M(:,:) inside.)

    use my_module, only: h, n, M
    use iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
    implicit none

    !! Dummy arguments.                                                             
    real(dp), dimension( n ) :: F, Cnew, Cold, Fold, x
    real(dp) :: alpha
    integer  :: converged

    !! Locals.                                                                      
    integer  :: iter, maxiter, j
    real(dp) :: alpha2, tol, normr
    real(dp), allocatable :: b(:), r(:), F2(:), Mr(:), p(:,:), Mp(:,:)

    !! This interface block should be deleted when Funct2() is defined in some module.
    interface
        function Funct2( Cnew, Cold, Fold, alpha ) result( ret )
            import dp, n
            real(dp) :: Cnew( n ), Cold( n ), Fold( n ), alpha, ret( n )
        endfunction
    endinterface

    allocate( b(n), r(n), F2(n), Mr(n), &
              p( n, maxiter ), Mp( n, maxiter ) )

    b(:)     =  -F(:)
    tol      =  5.e-3_dp
    maxiter  =  size( b )
    x(:)     =  0.0_dp
    r(:)     =  b(:)
    normr    =  norm2( r )  !! or sqrt(sum( r(:)**2 )) if norm2() not available     
    alpha2   =  1e-6_dp

    do iter = 1, maxiter

        !! Get preliminary search direction                                         
        p(:,iter) = r(:)

        !! Approximate the Jacobian(M) residual product                             
        Cnew(:)    = Cnew(:) + alpha2 * r(:)
        F2(:)      = Funct2( Cnew, Cold, Fold, alpha )        
        Mr(:)      = 1 / alpha2 * ( F2(:) - F(:) )
        Mp(:,iter) = Mr(:)

        !! Orthogonalize search direction                                           
        do j = 1, iter-1
            p(:,iter)  = p(:,iter)  - sum( Mp(:,j) * Mp(:,iter) ) * p(:,j)
            Mp(:,iter) = Mp(:,iter) - sum( Mp(:,j) * Mp(:,iter) ) * Mp(:,j)
        enddo

        !! Normalize search direction                                               
        p(:,iter)  = p(:,iter)  / norm2( Mp(:,iter) )
        Mp(:,iter) = Mp(:,iter) / norm2( Mp(:,iter) )

        !! Update solution and residual                                             
        alpha2 = sum( r(:) * Mp(:,iter) ) / sum( Mp(:,iter)**2 )
        x(:) = x(:) + alpha2 * p(:,iter)
        r(:) = r(:) - alpha2 * Mp(:,iter)

        !! Check convergence                                                        
        normr = norm2( r )

        if ( normr < tol ) then
            converged = 1
            return
        endif

    enddo  !! iter                                                                  

    if( normr > tol ) then
        print *, "SOLUTION DID NOT CONVERGE!!"
        converged = 0
    endif

endsubroutine
```

Some more details:

According to the above Matlab tutorial, column and row vectors are distinguished in Matlab, with a single quote (') representing [transpose](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/matlab_vector_transpose.htm), `*` represents [matrix multiplication](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/matlab_matrix_multiplication.htm), and [colon notation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/matlab_colon_notation.htm) seems very similar to that of Fortran.

In contrast, as explained in the Comments, there is no distinction between column and row vectors in Fortran. (As for making Nx1 or 1xN 2-dim arrays, please see another Answer.). Also, `*` represents element-wise multiplication rather than matrix multiplication, so `sum()` or `dot_product()` is necessary to calculate inner product.

Furthermore, matrices in Fortran do not change their size dynamically (e.g., by increasing columns or rows on the fly), so they need to be allocated with given size beforehand (where the allocation size can of course be determined dynamically).

Invocation of `Funct2()` may need some caution. If it is defined inside some module, then an interface block should *not* be provided (because it is automatically handled by the compiler). If `Funct2()` is defined outside modules, we need to write an interface block manually as shown above. Here I assume `Funct2()` is defined like this:

```
function Funct2( Cnew, Cold, Fold, alpha ) result( ret )
    use iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
    use my_module, only: n, M
    implicit none
    real(dp) :: Cnew(n), Cold(n), Fold(n), alpha
    real(dp) :: ret(n)

    !! do some multiplication by M(:,:)...
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use row vectors and column vectors with matrix notation in Fortran, you must allocate them as `(n,1)` and `(1,n)` arrays. For example

```
real :: x(10,1), A(10,10), chisq
chisq = matmul(transpose(x),matmul(A,x))
```

A 1-D array is neither a row nor a column vector, it's just an array. But that's usually all you need. The example above could be written like this with 1-D arrays:

```
real :: x(10), A(10,10), chisq
chisq = sum(x*matmul(A,x))
```

Arrays don't grow automatically, so the easiest thing to do in general is to allocate it with the max size needed, if you know what that's going to be. However, in your case it looks like you don't actually refer to previous values of `iter` in your algorithm. If `Mp` is just a work variable and not interesting in itself, then you can get away with having only a single column in `Mp` and updating that column rather than adding new columns.